# ASP.NET MVC List show Action link based on field value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a `html.displayfor(function(modelitem) item.submissionstatus)`.

Is it possible to just show the action links Edit / Details / Delete based on the value returned.

ie if the returned value is 'Unsubmitted' show all three links but if the returned value is 'Submitted' then only show the details link